# Simple JSON parseing on android issuese with output

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am working on learning JSON, and got pretty far with it.I got the parsing of the information out right. I debugged it and looked at the values and they are right. The issue is the output variable is getting Null Node. I just dont get why that is. I am a bit lost here. Any help will be appreciated.

So my main activity class is this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = "Test ME";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button bparsejson      = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bparsejson);
        final TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        final String strJson = "{ \"Android\" :[{\"song_name\":\"Gimme Dat\",\"song_id\":\"1932\",\"artist_name\":\"Sidney Samson (Feat. Pitbull & Akon)\"},{\"song_name\":\"F-k The Money (Remix)\",\"song_id\":\"73\",\"artist_name\":\"B.o.B. (Feat. Wiz Khalifa)\"}] }";
        final String outputData = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "I have started");
        /******** Listener for button click ********/
        bparsejson.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Button Pushed");
                JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
                jp.parsesData(strJson, outputData);
                output.setText(outputData);
            }
        });


    }


}
```

And my JSON parser is this.

```
    import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



/**
 * Created by MMILLAR on 1/20/2016.
 * JSON Parser Class
 * USe this to parse all data which is JSON
 */
public class JSONParser {
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    //String OutputData = "";
    //String jsonData = null;
    String TAG = "JSON Output: ";
    String TAG1 = "Value for JSON";

    //Consturctor
    public JSONParser()
    {
        //this.jsonData = jsonData;
       // this.OutputData = outPutData;
    }

    public String parsesData(String jsonData, String outputData)
    {
        try
        {
            //Creaate a new JSONObject ith the name/value mapping from the JSON string
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            //Returns the value mapped by the name if it exists and is a JSONArry
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");

            //Proccess the JSON node
            int lenghtJsonArrar = jsonMainNode.length();
            for (int i = 0; i<lenghtJsonArrar; i++)
            {
                //Get object for each json node
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                //Get the node values
                int song_id = Integer.parseInt(jsonChildNode.optString("song_id").toString());
                String song_name = jsonChildNode.optString("song_name").toString();
                String artist_name = jsonChildNode.optString("artist_name").toString();
                //Debug Testing code
                String songID = jsonChildNode.getString("song_id").toString();
                Log.d(TAG1,songID );
                String songName = jsonChildNode.getString("song_name").toString();
                Log.d(TAG1,songName );
                String artName = jsonChildNode.getString("artist_name").toString();
                Log.d(TAG1,artName );


                //create the output
                outputData += "Node: \n\n " + song_id + " | "
                                            + song_name + " | "
                                            + artist_name + " \n\n ";

                Log.d(TAG, outputData);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  outputData;
    }

}
```

And my xml activity layer is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ParseXmlAndroidExample" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bparsejson"
    android:text="Parse JSON Data Android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/output"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be here

```
//create the output
            outputData += "Node: \n\n " + song_id + " | "
                                        + song_name + " | "
                                        + artist_name + " \n\n ";
```

you are using `+= operator` which means

```
outputData = outputData + "Node: \n\n " + song_id + " | "
                                        + song_name + " | "
                                        + artist_name + " \n\n ";
```

But the initial value for outputData is null and hence the null result. All you have to do is to just initialise the outputData variable with empty string instead of null value.

```
 String outputData = "";
```

And also change your `setOnClickListener()` to this

```
 /******** Listener for button click ********/
    bparsejson.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Button Pushed");
            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            output.setText(jp.parsesData(strJson, outputData));
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help..!!

Comment: Yes that worked, I didnt even think about the += issue. Thank you very much I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the value returned from the method:

```
outputData = jp.parsesData(strJson, outputData);
```

At the moment you just ignore it.

Furthermore, `outputData` must not be final otherwise you can't change it.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be problematic that he's passing a `final String` to the method and trying to change its value there?

Comment: @JustinPowell yes, thanks. Did not see that. Changing in the method is not a problem as the parameter is not final.